# Printing an equal number of a's and b's recursively in Python

Tags: python, string, recursion

I was wondering how to print strings of a's and b's of an equal amount using recursion.  For example, if the input is "4", the outputs would be aabb abab bbaa, baba, baab, and abba.

This is what I have so far:

```python
def ab_equal(length, current):
    if length == 0:
        print(current)
    else:
        k = -1
        ab_equal(length - 1, current + "a")
        ab_equal(length - 1, current + "b")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(ab_equal(4, " "))
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to count a's and b's:

```
def ab_equal(length, current, a=None, b=None):
    if a is None:
        a = b = length // 2
    if length == 0:
        print(current)
    else:
        if a:
            ab_equal(length - 1, current + "a", a - 1, b)
        if b:
            ab_equal(length - 1, current + "b", a, b - 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ab_equal(4, "")
```

```
aabb
abab
abba
baab
baba
bbaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like so would work:

```py
def ab_equal(length, current=""):

    if len(current) == length:
        if current.count("a") == current.count("b"):
            print(current)
    else:
        ab_equal(length, current + "a")
        ab_equal(length, current + "b")


ab_equal(4)
```

```
aabb
abab
abba
baab
baba
bbaa
```

Since we don't have to return (and only print) you can print out at the end the call stack.